# missing dataset in Reporting Services Report after Moving TFS

Tags: reporting-services, tfs-reports

We recently moved our Team Foundation Server (TFS) to a new server, and I am now trying to setup the reports once more.  When I run the reports I get this error:

An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted) 
Query execution failed for dataset 'dsIteration'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand) 
For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors

Or

An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted) 
Query execution failed for dataset 'dsPlatform'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand) 
For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors

I created a new Team Project, and when I ran the reports from that project I got the same errors.

Where can I find these datasets or is there a way form me to redeploy all the report information to the new report server?

Answer (score 0):

The cube on your SSAS server is not correctly running. There is a good [blog post by Grant](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2010/07/12/administrative-report-pack-for-team-foundation-server-2010.aspx) how to deal with it

Answer (score -1):

Another Error as like as above:

An error has occurred during report processing. (rsProcessingAborted) Query execution failed for dataset 'dsPlatform'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand) For more information about this error navigate to the report server on the local server machine, or enable remote errors